# What does the temporary message banner at the top of the page say?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

What does the temporary message banner at the top of the page say? I can’t read the full message:

[image]

I can’t click on it, scroll it, or get any information about it at all!

Comment: it's clear, we need to build a kind and collaborative close icon! we need a better close icon

Comment: That "questions" text comes uncomfortably close to the "Newest" button also

Comment: Where's the button for the "Accurate and useful community"?

Comment: +1 for a screenshot where your battery is over 10%.

Comment: what happens if you turn your mobile device by 90° ?

Comment: @Patrick: nothing exciting happens. The screen becomes wider, and so shows more of the message. But I could still not see the full message, and it still was no scrollable or clickable. I dismissed the banner, so cannot take a screen shot.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The announcement banner was created prior to the rollout of responsive pages. We're working on fixing it.

Answer (score 29):

> Join us in building a kind, collaborative learning community via our updated [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

I guess it wasn't built for the mobile browser.

Comment: Yea, I guessed as much. :). I wanted to point out that the message will be lost to folks on a small screen.

Comment: All it needs to say is "don't slam newbs" which would fit.

Comment: @Fattie I think the correct message would be "vote down and close silently"

Comment: @gnat - that works

Comment: @Fattie: The CoC does include examples that go both ways, like this example of unfriendly conduct: “*If you bothered to read my question, you’d know it’s not a duplicate.*”  So, "don't slam noobs, and assume people who try to help are experts who are trying to actually help".  And, unlike the banner, doesn't talk about turning SO into a "learning community" rather than a collection of good answers to *useful* questions.  I was prepared to hate it, but it's all pretty reasonable and is fully compatible with downvoting and closing useless questions.

Comment: _it wasn't build for [...] mobile_ isn't this SO's mission statement?

Comment: @Tas No, no, no, you've got it all wrong. "We commit to providing all standard computer users with major browsers at exactly 100% zoom a relatively low-bug experience compared to those of mobile browsers, app users, and zoom zoomers." [(Source)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372153/what-does-the-temporary-message-banner-at-the-top-of-the-page-say/372155?noredirect=1#comment619382_372155)

Comment: @PeterCordes I feel somehow disappointed that you missed your opportunity to hate on the CoC :)

Comment: @DavyM How did you get the link for the comment?

Comment: @sohnryang By clicking on the time (Where it says `yesterday` or `x hours ago`), it links you directly to the comment. [The more you know...](https://youtu.be/Zmvt7yFTtt8)